# I am trying to delete account record using Postman tool. I have created apex class and method to delete account. but the account doesnt get deleted

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, postman

```
   @RestResource(urlmapping='/v1/Account/*')
global class AccountManager {
    @httpDelete
    global static String deleteAccount(){
    RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
    String requestURI = request.requestURI;
    System.debug('requestURI '+requestURI);
    String accountId = requestURI.subStringAfterLast('/');
    
    List<Account> accList = [Select Id From Account Where Id =: accountId ];
    if(accList != null && accList.size() >0){
        try{
            delete accList;
            return '{"message":"Account Record Deleted"}';
        }catch(System.Exception ex){
            String errrorMeesage = ex.getMessage();
            return '{"message":"'+errrorMeesage+'"}';
        }
    }else{
        return '{"message":"Account Record not Found"}';
    }
    }

    @httpGet
    global static AccountWrapper accountInformation(){
    RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
    String requestURI = request.requestURI;
    String accountId = requestURI.subStringAfterLast('/');
    
    List<Account> accountList = [Select Id, Name, Rating, 
    Industry, Description, Phone, Fax
    FROM Account Where Id =: accountId];
    
    List<Contact> contactList = [Select Id, Name, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone
    FROM Contact
    Where AccountId =: accountId ];
    
    List<Case> caseList = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description, Status, Owner.Name
    FROM Case
    Where AccountId =: accountId];
    
    AccountWrapper wrapper = new AccountWrapper();
    
    if(!accountList.isEmpty()){
        wrapper.accountRecord = accountList.get(0);
        wrapper.contactList = contactList;
        wrapper.caseList = caseList;
    }else{  }

    return wrapper;
    }


    global class AccountWrapper {
    global Account accountRecord;
    global List<Contact> contactList;
    global List<Case> caseList;
    }
```

}

//Postman
[image]

getting response like get method.  I have created get method as well.

Comment: You don't need to write any Apex to do this. Just use the native REST API.

Comment: but this code worked with workbech.

Comment: You mention about calling get in postman. Did you call DELETE api?

Comment: @metasync i have created two methods i.e get and delete api. there is no problem with get API method but when i call the delete API method using postman the record doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Your Postman shows a DELETE HttpRequest yet you are posting a JSON body - your apex code doesn't need this JSON body, just the ID on the URL string.  That said, David Reed is correct - OOTB SFDC REST API is all that is required here

Comment: @cropredy I am not passing JSON body. This is the result that I got when I hit delete API. Check the response it is 200.

Comment: my bad - that response looks like the response from the HttpGet

Comment: @cropredy yes it's a similar response.

Answer (score -1):

**You need to try this code as well and in postMan write key as 'id' not 'accid' or other
in my org its works well when i change 'accid' to 'id' in postman.**

```
@HttpDelete
    global static string deleteAccount(){
        
        map<string,string> paramsMap2=RestContext.request.params;
        string accountId2=paramsMap2.get('id');
        
        list<Account> acclistto=[select id from Account where id=:accountId2];
         if(!acclistto.isEmpty()){
           

            try{
                 delete acclistto;
                 return 'record deleted successfully';

        }catch(DMLException e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
         }else{
             
             return 'record not found';
         }
         
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: accid vs id makes 0 difference; the important part is to _be consistent_.